# Typescript tsc compiler complaining about property not existing despite me updating lib.dom.t.ts

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use webkitBackingStorePixelRatio on the HTML canvas.

A statement like:

```
context.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio
```

where context is the usual context of the HTML canvas, gives a type error in VSCode, as the webkitBackingStorePixelRatio property is not defined. I updated the CanvasRenderingContext2D interface in lib.dom.t.ts to this

```
interface CanvasRenderingContext2D extends CanvasCompositing, CanvasDrawImage, CanvasDrawPath, CanvasFillStrokeStyles, CanvasFilters, CanvasImageData, CanvasImageSmoothing, CanvasPath, CanvasPathDrawingStyles, CanvasRect, CanvasShadowStyles, CanvasState, CanvasText, CanvasTextDrawingStyles, CanvasTransform, CanvasUserInterface {
    mozBackingStorePixelRatio: any;
    msBackingStorePixelRatio: any;
    oBackingStorePixelRatio: any;
    backingStorePixelRatio: any;
    webkitBackingStorePixelRatio: any;
    readonly canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
}
```

Which resolves the VSCode error.

However compiling using tsc still gives the same error `Property 'webkitBackingStorePixelRatio' does not exist on type 'CanvasRenderingContext2D'.`

Is there a way to force the tsc from command line to use lib.dom.d.ts the way VScode does so the error doesn't happen? Or is this inadvisable?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like

> Blink and WebKit.
> Most of these APIs are deprecated and were removed shortly after Chrome 36.

([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D))